# Multiple aggregate functions in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

For this example I got 3 simple tables (Page, Subs and Followers):

[image: My three tables]

For each page I need to know how many subs and followers it has.
My result is supposed to look like this:

[image: Result]

I tried using the COUNT function in combination with a GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(s.UID) AS SubCount, COUNT(f.UID) AS FollowCount 
FROM page p, subs s, followers f 
WHERE p.ID = s.ID AND p.ID = f.ID AND s.ID = f.ID 
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Obviously this statement returns a wrong result.

My other attempt was using two different SELECT statements and then combining the two subresults into one table.

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(s.UID) AS SubCount FROM page p, subs s WHERE p.ID = s.ID GROUP BY p.ID
```

and

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(f.UID) AS FollowCount FROM page p, follow f WHERE p.ID = f.ID GROUP BY p.ID
```

I feel like there has to be a simpler / shorter way of doing it but I'm too unexperienced to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Next, learn what `COUNT()` does.  It counts the number of non-NULL values.  So, your expressions are going to return the same value -- because `f.UID` and `s.UID` are never `NULL` (due to the `JOIN` conditions).

The issue is that the different dimensions are multiplying the amounts.  A simple fix is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT s.UID) AS SubCount, COUNT(DISTINCT f.UID) AS FollowCount 
FROM page p JOIN
     subs s
     ON p.ID = s.ID JOIN
     followers f 
     ON s.ID = f.ID 
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

The inner joins are equivalent to the original query.  You probably want `left join`s so you can get counts of zero:

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT s.UID) AS SubCount, COUNT(DISTINCT f.UID) AS FollowCount 
FROM page p LEFT JOIN
     subs s
     ON p.ID = s.ID LEFT JOIN
     followers f 
     ON p.ID = f.ID 
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

Comment: Your solution works as long as a page doesn't have 0 followers or subs. I removed the last entry of my subs table so that the Page with ID 2 has 0 Subs and 4 Followers. Now ID 2 is not shown at all.  I replaced all joins with left joins. Now ID 2 is shown with the values 0 Subs and 0 Followers (although its 4 Followers). Do you know what I did wrong there?

Comment: @RolfWolf . . . The second join should be to `p.id`, not `s.id`.

Comment: The overhead of the cartesian product produced between `subs` and `followers` this way might be significant if the numbers are high. I think a solution with correlated subqueries is better in this case...

Comment: @LukasEder . . . Or by aggregating *before* joining.  My answer was directed to the way the OP originally framed the query.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar subquery should work in this case.

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       (SELECT Count(s_uid)
        FROM   subs s1
        WHERE  s1.s_id = p.id) AS cnt_subs,
       (SELECT Count(f_uid)
        FROM   followers f1
        WHERE  f1.f_id = p.id) AS cnt_fol
FROM   page p
GROUP  BY p.id;
```